# Matching specific parts of a string or else matching entire string

Tags: regex, sorting, expression, character

The idea here is to group log messages better from our application.

So imagine the regex:

```
(^Case1|^Case2|Case3$)
```

And the strings:

- teststring Case3
- Case1 teststring
- Case2
- teststring

The expected capture results would be

- Case3
- Case1
- Case2

(and nothing for the last one)

Since i dont want to discard messages that I don't specifically define, I'd like to capture the entire string if the string doesnt match any of the cases defined in the regex.

In naivety, I changed the code to:

```
(^Case1|^Case2|Case3$|.*)
```

However the last capture group now seems to override the capture done by the other groups, and is always the one that gets evaluated....so i always match the entire string....unless the text to match is at the start of the string.

eg
using:

```
(^Case1|^Case2|Case3$|.*)
```

on

- Case2 testString

gives

- Case2

but using

```
(^Case1|^Case2|Case3$|.*)
```

on

- teststring Case3

gives

- teststring Case3

Hopefully someone will enlighten me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My suggestion would be to check if it matches in the surrounding code, and if not, use the whole string, otherwise use the matched group. Otherwise your regular expression will get ugly, especially as the cases grow. As an example of how unpleasant this can be, here's a regular expression that seems to do what you're asking with a single match group: `(^Case1|^Case2|Case3$|(?:^(?<!(?:Case1|Case2))(?:.(?!Case3$))*$))`. I am *not* suggesting that you use this regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, i've used a combination of most answer on this page to cater for a few different use cases now. - Nothing too performance demanding...don't worry!

Also, thanks sln for your expanded answer...it really helped to improve my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited Note*  - Something to be aware of..

Regex is processed left to right in alternations.
*But*, it is processed at the current character position.
Example, in this expression `(here$)|.*` the `here$` is checked first at
character position 0, and the subject string is `'first here'`, the 'f' in 
first is checked against the 'h' in `here$`. No match ..

So, it goes to the next alternation expression `.*`, and it can match 'f'
and matches to the end of the string.

Even though the subject string contains a '... here' at the end, it won't match
it in this case.

If however, you had this regex `.*(here$)|.*`, the first `.*(here$)` would match because the
'f' can be matched all the way up to the 'here' at the end.

---

Technically you'd want to know which case matched, while at the same time
matching all the other text.

If so, there are many ways, here are two.

This uses a branch reset.

```
 # ^(?|(Case[12]).*|.*(Case3)|(.+))$

 ^ 
 (?|
      ( Case [12] )                 # (1)
      .* 
   |  
      .* 
      ( Case3 )                     # (1)
   |  
      ( .+ )                        # (1)
 )
 $
```

This uses individual capture groups to tell you specifically which case
matched.

```
 # ^(?:(Case[12]).*|.*(Case3)|(.+))$

 ^ 
 (?:
      ( Case [12] )                 # (1)
      .* 
   |  
      .* 
      ( Case3 )                     # (2)
   |  
      ( .+ )                        # (3)
 )
 $
```

Comment: The branch reset is a good idea, but not available in most regex flavors. [Another way using an initial lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/hU8xZ0/1): `(^Case[12]|^(?!.*Case3$).*|Case3$)` but I share @Lithis opinion.

Comment: @Jonny5 - I guess it's the strangeness. So you basically tie it up into a knot just for the sake of getting any case into a single capture group. Yet, it still doesn't tell you which case it is, you'd have to just do another string compare after the match. Otherwise `^(?:(^Case[12])|.*(Case3$)|(.+))` does the same thing, is much faster, and `$1$2` gives the case.